How to sort out this data based on a specific indicator in R
Here is a short my data and assume I have many many EX and Time.


df<- data.frame(
ID = c(1, 2),
Day1 = c(1, 1),
Type1 = c('A', 'B'),
EX1 = c(1, 3),
EX2 = c(4, 5),
Time1 = c(13, 15),
Time2 = c(9, 10),
Day2 = c(2, 2),
Type2 = c('B', 'D'),
EX3 = c(7, 6),
EX4 = c(8, 9),
Time3 = c(10, 4),
Time4 = c(6, 12)
)



And I want to get the following table


ID  Type    Exer    Time    Score
1   A   1   1   13
1   A   4   2   9
1   B   7   3   10
1   B   8   4   6
2   B   3   1   15
2   B   5   2   10
2   D   6   3   4
2   D   9   4   12



The logic is that based on Day 1 ( all 1) and Day2 (All 2) and we want to reshape the data.
Each row represents a Id's score for a specific time, along with the correct Type and Ex  information. The Type should be determined based on whether the time number falls under "Day1" or "Day2". So ID gets the Type based on Day 1 and Day 2.

Its still unclear how the type goes with time. ie Time4 for ID=1 is 6. How is this TypeB?

Thank you for your comment. If you look at Day2 , ID=1 gets Type2, i.e., B for Time3 and 4 , a sore of 10 and 6

But what signifies that day1 is for times 1 and 2 and day 2 is for times 3 &4? Is it the ordering of the data?

Yes, Day1 for Type1,   EX1,EX2... Time1, Time2... same for Day2

nms <- names(df)
i1 <- grepl('Time',nms)
i2 <- grepl('Day', nms)

n <- tapply(nms[i1], cumsum(i2)[i1], \(x)str_replace(min(x),"\\D+","Day"))

df %>%
  rename(set_names(nms[i2], n)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c('.value','score'), names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)')%>%
  fill(Day)%>%
  mutate(Type = Type[Day], .by = ID)

# A tibble: 8 × 6
     ID score   Day Type     EX  Time
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1         1 A         1    13
2     1 2         1 A         4     9
3     1 3         2 B         7    10
4     1 4         2 B         8     6
5     2 1         1 B         3    15
6     2 2         1 B         5    10
7     2 3         2 D         6     4
8     2 4         2 D         9    12


Thank you, Not sure Why I get this error, I just copied your codes: Error: object 'nms' not found

@user330 nms <- names(df) I forgot to include that line. will do so now
